# What do dotted stave lines mean?

Tags: notation, sheet-music

I’ve seen a dotted stave lines in this piece: http://www.fullinuyasha.com/inuyasha-sheet-music-sango-theme.html

What do they mean? How is this supposed to be played?

[image]

Comment: They don't seem to be there on all of the versions of this song.

Comment: I'd go for "cues" -- if this were an orchestra score for some instrument I'd read the upper part as either an "ossia" line or the notes from some other instrument.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically dotted stave lines suggest a continuation of the stave without having the stave actually be present.  Quite often you'd just see the top and bottom lines of the stave extended to where the stave re-appears in full.  This technique is predominately used for cut-away scores to help line things up.

In this context of what you presented however, there seems to be little function in the use of these lines.  The only thing I can think of would be that the author is attempting to show that the dotted portion is not always part of the song, or that that portion is performed by electronic accompaniment only.  Otherwise, there is really no need.